# Evaluate a condition on each element of a vector y in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to evaluate a condition on each element of a vector y so that I get a vector whose `i’th` element tells me whether `y[i]`satisfies the condition. Is there any way to do this without using loops? So far, I have tried the following:

```
dim = 3

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [dim])
y = tf.log(x)

tf1 = tf.constant(1)
tf0 = tf.constant(0)


x_0 = tf.tile([x[0]], [dim])

delta = tf.cond(tf.equal(y,x_0),  tf1, tf0))
sess = tf.Session()
a = np.ones((1,3))

print(sess.run(delta, feed_dict={x:a}))
```

For a given input `x`, I want `delta[i]` to be `1` if  `y[i] = x[0]` and `0` otherwise.

I get error

> shape must be of equal rank but are 0 and 1 for 'Select_2' (op: 'select') with input shapes [3], [],[]

I am new to TensorFlow, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you case, there is no need to use tf.cond, you can use tf.equal that does this without the loops, and because of the broadcasting there is no need to tile it. Just use:

```
dim = 3

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [dim])
y = tf.log(x)

delta = tf.cast(tf.equal(y,x[0]),tf.float32) # or integer type

sess = tf.Session()
a = np.ones((1,3))

print(sess.run(delta, feed_dict={x:a}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that you have error because you are trying to compare tensors with different shape.

That's working code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

dim = 3

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, dim), name='ktf')
y = tf.log(x)

delta = tf.cast(tf.equal(y, x[0]), dtype=tf.int32)

sess = tf.Session()
a = np.ones((1, 3))

print(sess.run(delta, feed_dict={x: a}))
```

Comment: Is there a solution that does not use loops?:)